# Conditionally Assign const value in js

Tags: javascript, node.js, if-statement, sequelize.js

I'm trying to assign a different value to `sequelize` based on whether the app is running locally or on the server. This is my code:

```
    const sequelize = production
  ? sequelizeHeroku.connect(Sequelize)
  : new Sequelize(database, user, password, {
      host,
      dialect: "mysql",
      pool: {
        max: 10,
        min: 0,
        acquire: 30000,
        idle: 10000
      }
    });
```

This doesn't work locally, as when I log the value of `sequelize` it is `false`. However, if I try to assign the variable like this:

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize(database, user, password, {
  host,
  dialect: "mysql",
  pool: {
    max: 10,
    min: 0,
    acquire: 30000,
    idle: 10000
  }
});
```

it works just fine. I also checked that `console.log(production == true)` prints out `false`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you checked if `production` has the value `false` or `"false"`?

Comment: I checked that production == true logs false

Comment: That doesn't mean anything, though `true == "false" //false` but `if("false")` would execute.

Comment: What VLAZ is saying is pretty correct. See if you do the following:
```const test = production ? "hello" : "world"```
you get `"hello"` if production is `"false"`
and you get `"world"` if production is `false`

that means you might be getting the value of the connect statement you wrote

Comment: I've got it set in an .env file as PRODUCTION=FALSE and then I read it in a config file by doing production : process.env.PRODUCTION

Comment: @Alk then I suspect even more strongly than before that you're getting a string value, not a boolean.

Comment: How would you alter the above to make it into a boolean?

Comment: `production == "true"` would tell you if it has the string value `"true"` which is convenient for turning the value into a boolean. But you might want to include more values that result in a boolean `true`, for example `"True"`, `"TRUE"`, `"T"` or others.

Comment: why not use `process.env.MODE === 'production'` ? production == 'true' is incorrect check

Comment: first of all use `===` instead of `==`, 
second use a correct variable name (IS_PRODUCTION as you expect boolean), 
third set MODE instead of PRODUCTION and string modes

Comment: thanks for the suggestions - setting mode with "dev" and "prod" works...happy to accept an answer if one of you posts it

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use `NODE_ENV` environment variable. E.g.

`index.ts`:

```js
import { Sequelize } from 'sequelize';
import assert from 'assert';

const database = 'sample';
const user = 'testuser';
const password = 'testpass';
const host = '127.0.0.1';

const sequelize =
  process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
    ? 'sequelize heroku'
    : new Sequelize(database, user, password, {
        host,
        dialect: 'mysql',
        pool: {
          max: 10,
          min: 0,
          acquire: 30000,
          idle: 10000,
        },
      });

assert(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production', 'NODE_ENV should be "production"');
assert(sequelize === 'sequelize heroku', 'Should use heroku sequelize in production environment');
```

Execute code in `production` environment:

```js
NODE_ENV=production npx ts-node ./index.ts
```

No assertion failed. It works as expected.